# $.ajax is not a function ( on full version of jQuery )

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

ajax is not a function on full version of jQuery ( i tried minified and cdn both ). first i thought it is because of bootstrap cdn so removed it but problem still there. i searched online and i find main issue due to slim version of jquery but here i used full versions and i tried so many version but problem is still there please help me

head data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css"> 
    
    <title>New Project</title>
</head>
```

my code

```
function save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/post',
            data: { name : "name", content : "content"},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
}
```

Comment: How do you connect your main script?

Comment: using <script> tag in html page

Comment: Are you including the script before or after including jquery?

Comment: In the network tab of developer tools, jQuery is loaded without any errors? It also loads before your script in the waterfall diagram?

Comment: at the botton of html page, after jQuery tag

Comment: Just before your error line, add `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)` and tell us exactly what that states.  This normally happens when you have 2 jquery script tags (without realising) and 2nd loads before your code runs.

Comment: check console errors if any and post them here.

Comment: 3.5.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-deprecated/ajax-event-alias,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector    it is result of console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)

Comment: in network tab i saw two jquerys, first is min and second is slim . they are load before my script without any error

Comment: one more thing im using ejs in index.ejs. i dont know its effect or not

Comment: No idea about "index.ejs", but there's your answer - your framework is loading **jquery.slim** after your jquery which replaces your jquery, so `$` = jquery.slim.  Use $.noConflict directly after you load jquery (not in doc.ready) https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `script` at the end of `body` tag

```
<body>
   //

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      function save(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: //url,
            data: //data,
            dataType: 'json'
         });
      }
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working